# Removing spaces from String and Print MIPS

Tags: mips, cpu-registers

So I'm trying to figure out, how I can remove the spaces from my String in Mips and then print it out again. My issue is with printing out. I get the error message Address out of range 00000.

I feel like my understanding of mips is limited so I'm at a complete loss of the next steps to take -

```
Message: .asciiz "Ridwaan Toure"

.text

main:

li $a1, 20        # I tried this to see if it would make any difference
la $t0, Message   # load the message into t0 register
li $t1, 0         # set the Counter to 0
la $t3, 32        # this is the ASCII for space 


 remove:
    lb $t2,0($t0)         # Load the byte that $t0 points to (first character)
    beqz  $t2, end       # if we reach the end of the String we're done $a3==0
    bne $t2,$t3, continue      # Since it's not a space we continue
    j skip

continue:

    add $t0, $t0, 1         # we ++ the pointer to point to next char
    add $t1, $t1, 1          #we increase our counter 
    j remove #loopAgain

skip:
   add $t0, $t0, 1   # we ++ the pointer to point to next char
   j remove          #loopAgain we didn't increase the counter

end:
li $v0, 4            # thought this would help print String but no dice
move $a0, $t2        # t2 should be loaded with the String
syscall

#End
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

If I use `la $a0`, Message it just loads the original message so nothing is changing at the address either.

Comment: You're never moving any characters in this code. Try implementing it in a higher-level language first, and once you have that working you can start translating it into MIPS assembly.

Comment: `# t2 should be loaded with the String` <-- No it isn't. The only thing you ever put in `$t2` in this code are individual characters.